# Can't Plot Graph from training Model in Multi classification

Tags: pytorch, training-data, mnist

Help me solve the problem/error the graph could not be plotted, i am a python beginner

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (938,)

My code is below

```
#code

mnist_trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
mnist_testset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

mnist_valset, mnist_testset = torch.utils.data.random_split(mnist_testset, [int(0.9 * len(mnist_testset)), int(0.1 * len(mnist_testset))])

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_trainset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_valset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_testset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

print("Training dataset size: ", len(mnist_trainset))
print("Validation dataset size: ", len(mnist_valset))
print("Testing dataset size: ", len(mnist_testset))

# visualize data
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
for i in range(1, 6):
  img = transforms.ToPILImage(mode='L')(mnist_trainset[i][0])
  fig.add_subplot(1, 6, i)
  plt.title(mnist_trainset[i][1])
  plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

#model = Model()
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

if (torch.cuda.is_available()):
  model.cuda()
  

no_epochs = 100
train_loss = list()
val_loss = list()
best_val_loss = 1
for epoch in range(no_epochs):
  total_train_loss = 0
  total_val_loss = 0

  model.train()

  # training
  for itr, (image, label) in enumerate(train_dataloader):

      if (torch.cuda.is_available()):
          image = image.cuda()
          label = label.cuda()

      optimizer.zero_grad()

      pred = model(image)

      loss = criterion(pred, label)
      total_train_loss += loss.item()

      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

  total_train_loss = total_train_loss / (itr + 1)
  train_loss.append(total_train_loss)
```

I searched all previous issues and could not get through about the solutions

I have posted the code

Comment: Can you please post (1) the full traceback, (2) the code where you set the value of `no_epochs`, and (3) the code where you append values to `train_loss` and `val_loss`? Perhaps post the entire training code if you're unsure about (2) and (3). Please post them as an edit to the question, *not* as a reply comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, i have added most of the code

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. However, you seem to miss the full traceback. Can you post that as well? It's the full error text printed on the screen, starting with "Traceback" at the top.